# Error with VLC subtitles

Tags: 16.04, vlc

my problem is that I am running Ubuntu 16.04 with Vlc 2.2.0 things were going fine
before two days from now all i did was

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

now my VLC is 3.0.0 and the problem is subtitle loaded but not showing on screen.
tried removing VLC and reinstall it but that didn't worked.
tried restoring default configuration and that also didn't worked.
tried to edit

```
usr/share/applications/vlc.desktop
```

making

```
Exec=/usr/bin/vlc --started-from-file %m
```

instead of

```
Exec=/usr/bin/vlc --started-from-file %U
```

and also nothing changed.
any help will be thanked.
**Edit:** i find out something strange maybe it's new with VLC 3.0.0 but before when i change aspect ratio it shows the new aspect ratio in the top right corner of the screen but now nothing is there.

Comment: Does this happen with all video files?  What is the type of file (mp4, mkv, etc.)?

Comment: all video files (at least known ones "mp4,mkv,avi..")

Comment: VLC is 2.2.2 in Ubuntu 16.04 and it wouldn't change with apt-get upgrade, unless you added a PPA or installed VLC from somewhere else.

Comment: That is correct my friend.. i've followed a solution from Ubuntu forums which was to add new PPA but now i can't remember which one..
but does that make things worst??

Comment: @NourAlhadiMahmoud Probably. That makes things sort of "unsupported".